# Python: Sqlalchemy messing up pyinstaller?

Tags: python, opencv, sqlalchemy, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my program using pyinstaller. The code runs fine on windows, and uses SqlAlchemy, OpenCV and pyodbc packages.

I ran pyinstaller to create the executable and tried to run it. I'm getting an error:

```
ImportError: No module named ConfigParser
```

now, I reran the same thing and looked at logs from pyinstaller and got a warning:

```
WARNING: Hidden import "sqlalchemy.sql.functions.func" not found!
```

along with a few others.
then there was a warning about trying to import ConfigParser in lower and uppercase.

```
 Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowercases: ConfigParser
```

What might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

So, I figured it out. To an extent.
Seems like pyInstaller doesn't deal with SWIG files that well.

In `sqlalchemy.utils` there's a file called `compat.py`. It is there to make the module compatible with all versions of python.

for example, in python2.x, there's `ConfigParser` whereas in py3, it is named `configparser`
So there is a part in compat.py to deal with it:

```
if py3:
    import configparser
    # Some other such import statements
elif py2:
    import ConfigParser as configparser
```

Now, pyinstaller gets stumped here as it just focuses on the import, and hence it tries to import both and fails miserably.
My crude workaround to this involved modifying the compat.py file and retaining only the parts relevant to the python version I have (2.x).
Running pyinstaller again proved to be a success! :)

Although this is all very crude and there's probably something better out there, but I couldn't find anything, so I'm sharing what worked for me.